# Как подключать js скрипты в blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Я скачал готовый темплейт, теперь не понимаю, как подключить js файлы. Я читал документацию и знаю, что нужно использовать `@using Microsoft.JSInterop`.
Собственно, я вот так подключал самописные скрипты:

```
Inject] public IJSRuntime Js { get; set; }
    protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        => Js.InvokeVoidAsync("kinX").AsTask();
```

С bootstrap, jquery и тд это все не выходит. Вот файлы, которые мне необходимо подключить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так никто не обещал, что можно подключить всё что угодно.

Comment: А для чего именно они Вам нужны? Вы намерены обращаться к ним через `JSInterop` ?

Comment: @4per насколько я знаю, `JSInterop` позволяет вызывать методы из js скриптов. Но, например, в bootstrap вообще непонятно, какие методы вызывать

Comment: Вы не сможете использовать готовые js библиотеки через `JsInterop` напрямую.